# Paso de parametro en una funcion - Lista enlazada en C

Tags: c, lista, punteros, dev-c++

Buenas mi nombre es Marcelo.
Mi consulta es algo en específico sobre un módulo del codigo en particular. Es un ejercicio simple que me piden y lo pude resolver, pero no de la forma que quise. 
Contexto:
[image: CONSIGNA]

Mi código inicial fue este:

```
typedef char string[30];

typedef struct{
    int codProducto;
    string descripcion;
    float precioU;
}regProducto; 

typedef struct nodo {
    regProducto dato;
    struct nodo * siguiente;
}tListaProducto; 

tListaProducto * lista;

void menu();
void inicializarLista();
bool listaVacia();
void insertarElemento(regProducto pDato);
void insertarPrimerElemento(regProducto pDato);
void insertarAdelante(regProducto pDato);
void lecturaDatos(regProducto pProducto);
void visualizarLista();

int main() {
    inicializarLista();
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void inicializarLista() {
    lista=NULL;
}

void menu() {
    int opcion;
    regProducto producto;
    printf("MENU - GESTION DE LISTA DE PRODUCTOS\n\n");
    printf("Seleccione que desea hacer: ");
    printf("\n 1-Agregar producto a la lista.\n 2-Mostrar producto añadido.\n 3-SALIR\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcion); fflush(stdin);
    switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            lecturaDatos(producto);
            insertarElemento(producto);
            menu();
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Lista de productos:\n");
            visualizarLista();
            menu();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            printf("Opcion ingresada incorrecta. Se volvera al MENU.\n\n");
            menu();
            break;
    }
}
```

**¿DONDE ESTÁ EL PROBLEMA?**
En el *case 1:* del Switch.
En el menu creo una variable auxiliar *producto* del tipo regProducto para leer los datos (codProducto, descripcion, precioU). Paso como parametro esta variable a lecturaDatos(*producto*). lecturaDatos() la defino asi:

```
void lecturaDatos(regProducto pProducto) { 
printf("Inserte el codigo del producto: ");
scanf("%d", &pProducto.codProducto); fflush(stdin);
printf("\nInserte la descripcion del producto: ");
gets(pProducto.descripcion); fflush(stdin);
printf("\nIngrese el precio $ del producto: ");
scanf("%f", &pProducto.precioU); fflush(stdin);
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa y visualizo los datos, aparece el error. No visualiza los datos que ingrese. Como se aprecia en la imagen:

[image: ejecucion con funcion lecturaDatos()]

**¿Solucion?**
Elimine la funcion lecturaDatos(regProducto producto) y puse las instrucciones sueltas en **case 1**:

```
    case 1:
        printf("Inserte el codigo del producto: ");
        scanf("%d", &producto.codProducto); fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nInserte la descripcion del producto: ");
        gets(producto.descripcion); fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nIngrese el precio $ del producto: ");
        scanf("%f", &producto.precioU); fflush(stdin);
        insertarElemento(producto);
        menu();
        break;
```

Cuando ejecute el programa, ingrese los datos y los mostré, si se imprimieron los datos que ingresé.
¿Cual es el error? Yo quiero utilizar la funcion lecturaDatos() para que quede más prolijo el código y no todos los printf sueltos en case 1.
Probe utilizar la funcion lecturaDatos() sin parámetros también (ya que la variable "producto" está declarada dentro de la funcion menu() la cual incluye a lecturaDatos()) pero tampoco funciona. Tampoco declarando **regProducto producto;** como funcion global, al comienzo del codigo.

No pongo el resto del código porque no sé si será necesario, pero de serlo lo hago. Porque el problema está en la funcion lecturaDatos y su parámetro.

Answer (score 0):

creo haber entendido tu pregunta, tienes tu funcion de esta forma:

```
void lecturaDatos(regProducto pProducto) {
```

Cuando tu le pasas tu variable de producto se crea una copia del objeto producto y dentro de tu funcion se modifica la copia y no tu objeto que tu deseas que se modifique.

Lo que necesitarias seria pasarle el objeto por referencia para que no se cree una copia, si no me equivoco seria algo asi:

```
void lecturaDatos(regProducto *pProducto) { 
    printf("Inserte el codigo del producto: ");
    scanf("%d", &pProducto->codProducto); fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nInserte la descripcion del producto: ");
    gets(&pProducto->descripcion); fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese el precio $ del producto: ");
    scanf("%f", &pProducto->precioU); fflush(stdin);
}
```

Y al llamarla le pasas tu objeto por referencia:

```
lecturaDatos(&producto);
```

De esta forma, si le pasas a la funcion tu objeto que deseas modificar y no una copia.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por responder Lo pensé también, porque dije será porque estoy pasando copias en vez del contenido dentro de esa dirección, pero tampoco me dejó poner void lecturaDatos(regProducto &pProducto) {
Me saltó el error: [Error] expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token.

Comment: Hola amigo, investigue un poco as de apuntadores en c, ya que tenia tiempo que no los utilizaba, y he editado mi respuesta, quiza ahora si ya te sea de ayuda

Comment: Lo he compilado y probado y se han mostrado los datos de manera correcta, espero te sea util.

Comment: Hola Edmundo disculpa por no haber respondido más, pero tuve que pasar a otro tema porque he rendido hoy el examen. En su momento intenté como dijiste y me tiraba error de compilación, mañana voy a intentar volver a hacerlo bien desde cero e intentando pasar de nuevo por referencia, porque en tu codigo no veo error de sintaxis, no sé porque me tiraba error a mi. De nuevo gracias!